# I am trying to use the draw image method, but can't get it to work

Tags: c#, oop, drawimage

I am trying to draw an image on my form, on top of a picture box which has a background on it selected by the user. From my research, I gather that using this method is the best way to just flat out draw an image anywhere on a form. I'm new to using this method, here is what I have :

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create image.
        Image newImage =  Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\logoGreyHybridText.png");

        // Create coordinates for upper-left corner.

        // of image and for size of image.
        int x = 100;
        int y = 100;
        int width = 450;
        int height = 150;

        // Draw image to screen.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, x, y, width, height);

    }
```

If anybody has some advice, or if I am flat out using this wrong, feel free to chime as I just have one semester of OOP under my belt. (We are still in console apps in class ;-])

Comment: You are mixing up a Click event with a Paint event.  Wait for the next semester.

Comment: I am wanting this to take place when the user clicks a certain button. Obviously I know my code doesn't work, that's why I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Hans stated - you seem to have an odd statement where you are mixing up the click event with the paint event.

If you have this method hooked up to the click event:

```
button3.Click += button3_Click;
```

Your method arguments for button3_Click would be

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { // code here // }
```

I am unclear what you are actually trying to do. (i.e. Are you trying to draw this image over an image drawn in a picture box? The x,y coordinate of 100, 100 is that relative to the position of the picture box or another control object?)

All the same, try the following code and it will get you on a better track compared to where you are now.

Assuming that you are using the click event as I describe above, and not the paint event, your code would look something like this:

I will show you two ways of doing this - first 'the wrong way', but this is closer to what you have above.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If this is only an exercise this is acceptable, otherwise you should
    // store the image as a resource
    Image newImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\logoGreyHybridText.png");

    Graphics graphics = controlToDrawOver.CreateGraphics();

    // Note rectangle x,y coordinates are relative to 
    // the 'controlToDrawOver' object.
    Rectangle rectangleAreaToDrawImage = new Rectangle(100, 100, 450, 150);
    graphics.DrawImage(newImage, rectangleAreaToDrawImage);

}
```

*** Important Note *** 
Regardless of the code above, you should be drawing in the controls paint event handler, not the controls click event handler as your code appears to show. Every time the control is repainted your changes will be lost.

Therefore - here is 'the better way':

If you have to wait for the button to be clicked you could do something like this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    controlToDrawOver.Paint -= ControlPaintEventHandler;
    controlToDrawOver.Paint += ControlPaintEventHandler;
}

private void ControlPaintEventHandler(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // If this is only an exercise this is acceptable, otherwise you should
    // store the image as a resource
    Image newImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\logoGreyHybridText.png");

    // Note rectangle x,y coordinates are relative to 
    // the 'controlToDrawOver' object.
    Rectangle rectangleAreaToDrawImage = new Rectangle(100, 100, 450, 150);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, rectangleAreaToDrawImage);

}
```

Comment: This worked JHubbard80. Thanks for giving me some guidance on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Hey @JHubbard80, this is an old question but do you mind explaining why you did a -=  before a += on the ControlPaintEventHandler? Thanks!

Comment: To avoid adding the event handler multiple times. I only want ControlPaintEventHandler to trigger once on paint, not once per time the button has been previously clicked.  Adding the -= removes any previous ControlPaintEventHandler if they previously were associated with the paint event. If they were not associated than it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Add handler to PictruBox.Paint event and try to draw in it.
Also you can directly set image to PictureBox.Image property, it draw you image on picture box.

By your code, plase provide full form code. I think that main error - you draw picture in form coordinate system, so may be you draw your image out of PictureBox. Also what event hanble your method?